# Implement Google Assistant in an older version of android

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

does anyone experience in implementing Google Assistant with Actions Builder SDK into android 5.1 devices?

The purpose of putting the Google Assistant into the android device is to let it works as a chatbot.

I went through Google official [tutorial 1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-sdk-1#0) and [tutorial 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-sdk-2#0), I wonder how is node module can be implemented with Java?

Comment: It seems like Google Assistant should work on [Android 5.0+](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7172657?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en). Is that not working for your device?

Comment: it is missing from my device, and I would like to customise the google assistant on my device.